# Disable button when download is in progress Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using angular 4 in my app. I implemented a download funtionality which will be processed after clicking one button. When download will finished user will see the download link below. Now the download data are coming from rest api. I am using ngx-progressbar to show progress while downloading. When user will click the download button each time he will get a notification "OK" or "Not Ok" (if error occurs in newtwork). I am very new in handling angular stuff now. I would like to disable the button while download is in progress.But in my case all the timeI can click the button, even it is in progress. I would like to kno whow can I make my button disabled. Here is my code. I am giving only related code for that

**RESOLVED CODE**

angular.ts

```
import { NgProgress } from 'ngx-progressbar';

export class downloadReportComponent implements OnInit {

private buttonDisabled: boolean = false;

constructor( private websocketService: WebSocketService,
             public progressService: NgProgress) {
             }

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.authService.userSnapshot;
    this.loadReportConfig();
    this.downloadReport();
}

downloadReport(){
    //download report code
}
startLoading() {
    this.progressService.start();
    this.buttonDisabled=true;
}

stopLoading() {
    this.progressService.done();
    this.buttonDisabled=false;
}

doTestReport() {
    this.buttonDisabled=true;
    this.disco.getResourceTree().subscribe( api => {

        this.http.get( api.metrics.test.uri )
            .subscribe( r => {
                if(r!=null) {
                    this.notificationService.showOK("OK");
                    this.buttonDisabled=false;
                }
                }, e => {
                this.notificationService.showError( "not so OK" );
                console.log( "error", e );
            } );
    } );
```

HTML Code:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="right" class="overview-actions">
<mat-card-actions >
<button class="material-icons" (click)="doTestReport()" [disabled]="buttonDisabled" >&#xE149;</button>
</mat-card-actions>
</div>
<ng-progress
        [minimum]="0.15"
        [maximum]="1"
        [positionUsing]="'marginLeft'"
        [direction]="'leftToRightIncreased'"
        [color]= "'#f5f5f5'"
        [trickleSpeed]="500"
        [thick]="true"
        [ease]="'linear'">
</ng-progress>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a condition to your button :

```
<button class="material-icons" (click)="doTestReport()" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">&#xE149;</button>
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Bind the disabled property to the button.

Create the checkDownload boolean in your component.ts file and set it to true when you have started your download and set it to false when the download is completed or you've stopped it.

```
<button class="material-icons" [disabled]="checkDownload" (click)="doTestReport()" >&#xE149;</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
checkDownload = false;

downloadStart() {
this.checkDownload = true;
// your download code
// download completed.
this.checkDownload = false;
}

downloadStop() {
// Stop code
this.checkDownload = false;
}
```

Comment: how can I call downloadstart() and download stop method here. Sorry I am very new in angular

Comment: Those are just naming conventions i have used to give you an example.
Just create the variable and set it to true when download starts and set it to false when download completes.